# Parentheses in shell script if statements

Tags: sh

I working on a project at the moment that uses a bit of **Linux shell script**, and I'm finding myself writing snippets of code that look like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

x=1

if [ $x -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Hello, Dave!"
fi

if command -v pip3 >/dev/null ; then
    echo "PIP3 is already present."
fi
```

The above seems to work perfectly well, but it upsets my sense of inner harmony. Why should the first if statement only function properly with square brackets, while the second will only function properly without? That's (largely) a rhetorical question; I have a vague understanding that it's something to do with the fact that `[ expression ]` is actually an abbreviation for `test expression`. But it still looks *ugly*.

I seem to have come across an way of ameliorating the ugliness, by putting **parentheses** in the second if statement, i.e.

```sh
if ( command -v pip3 >/dev/null ); then
    echo "PIP3 is already present."
fi
```

Obviously it's subjective, but I find the above a lot easier on the eyes, especially when the command which the if statement is assessing is quite long. But, putting aesthetics to one side, my concern now is: **Could using parentheses as above have unintended consequences?** My grasp of what exactly `( command )` does is even weaker than my understanding of square brackets, but I'm told that it runs said command in a subshell. That doesn't sound like it would cause problems, but I'd be grateful to be told if my use of parentheses is imprudent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[` is indeed a synonym for `test`. The following are equivalent:

```
if [ $x -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "Hello, Dave!"
fi

if test $x -eq 1; then
  echo "Hello, Dave!"
fi
```

In your second example, the parentheses are somewhat redundant. They create a subshell command, in which the enclosed command is executed by a subshell, rather than by the current shell. Often, adding the parentheses makes no practical difference, but that's not always the case. Consider the following artificial example.

```
x=1
if ( x=3; true ); then
    echo $x
fi
```

versus

```
x=1
if x=3; true; then
    echo $x
fi
```

If you really need something to "enclose" the condition, use braces:

```
if { x=3; true; } then
     echo $x
fi
```

but I would recommend adjusting your idea of what shell code *should* look like.

Comment: Thank you. +1 and accepted. For the benefit of those who - like myself! - have a fairly tenuous grasp of shell script, could you explain **why it's safe to enclose commands in braces**. You're the expert, and not me, but I had been led to believe that braces in shell script are more than just punctuation; like square brackets, they tell the terminal to do specific things.

Comment: Yes; they tell the terminal to treat the contents as a single command. It's more apparent if  you use a redirection: `{ read a; read b; } < file.txt` sets `a` and `b` to the first and second lines of `file.txt`, respectively. The file is opened once, and the second read picks up where the first left off; contrast with `read a < file.txt; read b < file.txt`, which would set both variables to the first line of the file.

Comment: Braces are also not part of function definition syntax; a function simply requires a single command as its body, with the command group being the most commonly used command. `foo () for i in 1 2 3; do echo $i; done` is also a valid definition, with the `for` loop making up the body of the function.